# javascript get array from another function

Tags: javascript

```
<html>  
 <body>
            var el = document.getElementById("tab");
            var tab = Table(el, data);
            tab.showData();
            tab.takeData();
            var PieChart=drawPieChart(canvas);  
 </body>
</html>

<script> 
function Table(el, data) {
...
...
return{
showData: function(){
...
...
}
takeData: function(){
 var myData=new Array();
for (var i = 0; i < val2; i++) {
            myData[i] = document.getElementById('polja' + i).value;
}
}
...
...
};
}


function drawPieChart(canvas){
...
...
return{
 getmyData(

);
...
...
    };
    }
  </script>
```

how can i get myData in function "drawPieChart" except making myData global variable? thx
i was thinking in html make somthing like this PieChart.getMyData(Table.takeData); or something like that

Comment: Is it just me or is `myData` nowhere in your code?

Comment: Also, your code is not correct. You aren't including the JS code inside of a `script` tag, and you don't appear to have correct JS syntax either. Is this working for you?

Comment: jep.it's working. i have around 200 lines of code so i just put the things i thought are important.
but maybe i just make it more complicated

Answer (score 0):

Based on your edit, you can do this:

```
function Table(el, data) {
  var myData = new Array();  // Not global but accessible to every function that gets returned here
  return{
     // removed unnecessary code
     takeData: function(){
         for (var i = 0; i < val2; i++) {
            myData[i] = document.getElementById('polja' + i).value;
         } 
     },
     function drawPieChart(canvas){
         // Can access myData here
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok, the way you formatted the code makes it appear that you can.

Answer (score 0):

First, the problems with your code:

1. You have a block of JavaScript sitting inside `<body>`. This is not standard, not allowed, and will fail. Specifically, it will be displayed as text on the page, rather than being executed as JavaScript. All JavaScript must be located in one of the following places: an inline `<script>` tag, an external file that you load with a `<script>` tag, an event attribute such as `onload="..."`, or an attribute that can run JavaScript, such as `href="javascript:..."` on `<a>` elements.
2. You have a syntax error in the object you're returning from `Table()`; there is no comma separator between the hash key/value pairs (`showData()` and `takeData()`). The comma is required.
3. You have some uninitialized variables, including `val2`, `data`, and `canvas`. You probably just excerpted your code to omit the relevant initialization, but you should try to present complete self-contained code samples when asking questions on Stack Overflow.

With regard to your question, the object `tab` you are returning from `Table()` looks an awful lot like an instance object of a class in any OO language. JavaScript supports the OO paradigm via the prototype pattern, so a sensible approach would be to make `Table` a full class by defining its prototype. If you do this, you can make `tab` a full instance of `Table` by creating it with the `new` operator, and then you can store the `myData` array as an attribute on `tab`. Here's a random demonstration based on your sample code:

http://jsfiddle.net/awytnngu/

HTML:

```
<div id="tab">
    <input id="polja0" value="def1"/>
    <input id="polja1" value="def2"/>
    <input id="polja2" value="def3"/>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function Table(el,data) {
    this.el = el;
    return this;
}
Table.prototype.showData = function() {
    // ...
};
Table.prototype.takeData = function() {
    this.myData = new Array();
    var val2 = this.el.children.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < val2; ++i)
        this.myData[i] = document.getElementById('polja'+i).value;
};
Table.prototype.drawPieChart = function(canvas) {
    alert(this.myData);
};

var el = document.getElementById('tab');
data = 'whatever';
var tab = new Table(el,data);
tab.showData();
tab.takeData();
canvas = 'whatever';
var PieChart = tab.drawPieChart(canvas);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to throw in another possible approach, much simpler than the prototype solution, you can take an OUT parameter on `takeData()` and then pass it as an argument to `drawPieChart()`:

http://jsfiddle.net/uv8bh6nj/

HTML:

```
<div id="tab">
    <input id="polja0" value="def1"/>
    <input id="polja1" value="def2"/>
    <input id="polja2" value="def3"/>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function Table(el,data) {

    return {
        showData:function() {
            // ...
        },
        takeData:function(OUT) {
            OUT.myData = new Array();
            var val2 = el.children.length; // closure
            for (var i = 0; i < val2; ++i)
                OUT.myData[i] = document.getElementById('polja'+i).value;
        }
    };

}

function drawPieChart(canvas,myData) {
    alert(myData);
}

var el = document.getElementById('tab');
data = 'whatever';
var tab = new Table(el,data);
tab.showData();
var takeDataOUT = {};
tab.takeData(takeDataOUT);
canvas = 'whatever';
var PieChart = drawPieChart(canvas,takeDataOUT.myData);
```